# Canvas click events screwed up when browser window shrinks/moves

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been playing around with creating a hexagonal grid in HTML5 Canvas. I have a basic grid, where if you click a hex it will highlight the hex (demo here: http://cfiresim.com/hex-map-game-reboot/test.html)

In javascript, I am defining the canvas as such (some parts omitted for brevity):

```
 var hex = {};
 hex.canvas = document.getElementById("HexCanvas");
 hex.ctx = null;
 console.log("Initializing new game...");
 this.radius = 20;
 this.side = Math.round((3 / 2) * this.radius);
 this.height = Math.round(Math.sqrt(3) * this.radius);
 this.width = Math.round(2 * this.radius);

 //Set Size of main div to size of canvas
 $('#primary-panel').css('height', (hex.height * hex.rows)+hex.height*2);
 hex.canvas.style.width='100%';
 hex.canvas.style.height='100%';
 hex.canvas.width  = hex.canvas.offsetWidth;
 hex.canvas.height = hex.canvas.offsetHeight;

 //Set click eventlistener for canvas
 this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.clickEvent.bind(this), false);

 this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

All of the code can be found here: https://github.com/boknows/hex-map-game-reboot

My primary question is:  Is there a specific way to prevent the click events from getting all screwy when the canvas is resized via the browser? For example, if you shrink the browser to be just bigger than the grid, clicks dont register in the right place. Am I missing some feature of canvas? Maybe getSelectedTile() is not being defined correctly?

Edit: It seems like this primarily happens when the browser scrolls a little, and thus moves the grid off screen. The clicks then register with a weird offset, which I'm guessing is equal to the distance the screen scrolled. Advice?

Comment: First of all, very cool project! 2nd, I'm not seeing things get screwed up in chrome when I resize. Clicks seem to be registering fine when at all sizes including just bigger than the grid.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I guess I'm in Firefox, but it basically boils down to scrolling. If I scroll to the side, or move the grid in any way, clicks register with this weird offset (probably proportional to how much I scrolled).

So, do you lock the scrollbars? Seems like there must be a better way to prevent that.  If you add any sort of UI (like menus on the side or anything) you might end up scrolling.

Comment: Okay, I tried it in FF and I see what you're saying. It's the menus pushing things around. Those don't show up in Chrome. I'll play around in a bit and see if I can find the issue. I've got some hexagon drawing code here if you want to play around with it. (view source) http://kaatman.com/game/revengewar/ I was going to make a Risk type game but lost motivation.

Comment: Ha. I, too, am going for a risk-like game... and lost motivation awhile ago.  I actually had a semi-working version, but it was spaghetti code.  This is sort of a rework.  I've always had issues with aligning things with canvas objects and/or Bootstrap.

Comment: I assume you've read this? http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: Indeed I have. Love amit's work. It's not the hexagons that got me sidetracked, but everything else to coordinate ☺️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must take into a position of a page scroll.

In [HexagonGrid.js](https://github.com/boknows/hex-map-game-reboot/blob/master/js/HexagonGrid.js#L219), instead of this:

```
hex.clickEvent = function(e) {
        var mouseX = e.pageX;
        var mouseY = e.pageY;
```

Do this:

```
hex.clickEvent = function(e) {
        var mouseX = e.pageX - window.pageXOffset;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - window.pageYOffset;
```

Comment: That does indeed work! I think that I was confused because further down the clickEvent handler chain, I use canvas.getBoundingClientRect() which I know DOES take into account scrolling. I never thought that the original click wouldn't take that into account.